# Installing MPICH2 on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, mpi, failed-installation

I type in the command "apt-get install mpich2" but I get an error in the end:

http://pastebin.com/swZfhy1X

Any advices guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a broken package, coz one of its dependencies blcr-dkms is broken. This is the error in make.log

> /var/lib/dkms/blcr/0.8.2/build/cr_module/kbuild/vmadump_common.c:
>   In function ‘vmadump_thaw_proc’:
>   /var/lib/dkms/blcr/0.8.2/build/cr_module/kbuild/vmadump_common.c:1092:38:
>   error: ‘struct signal_struct’ has no
>   member named ‘count’
>   /var/lib/dkms/blcr/0.8.2/build/cr_module/kbuild/vmadump_common.c:
>   In function ‘vmadump_freeze_proc’:
>   /var/lib/dkms/blcr/0.8.2/build/cr_module/kbuild/vmadump_common.c:1999:38:
>   error: ‘struct signal_struct’ has no
>   member named ‘count’ make[2]: ***
>   [/var/lib/dkms/blcr/0.8.2/build/cr_module/kbuild/vmadump_common.o]
>   Error 1 make[1]: ***
>   [/var/lib/dkms/blcr/0.8.2/build/cr_module/kbuild]
>   Error 2 make: ***
>   [*module*/var/lib/dkms/blcr/0.8.2/build]
>   Error 2 make: Leaving directory
>   `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic

you might want to report a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/blcr/+filebug

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in Ubuntu 11.04:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/blcr/+bug/700036

When I tried to install mpich2 on my Ubuntu VmWare image I got the same error as you, but it seems to have installed anyway.

```
    marcus@ubuntu:~/Oracle$ mpich2version 
    MPICH2 Version:     1.3.1
    MPICH2 Release date:    Wed Nov 17 10:48:28 CST 2010
    MPICH2 Device:      ch3:nemesis
    MPICH2 configure:   --build=i686-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --        includedir=${prefix}/include --mandir=${prefix}/share/man --infodir=${prefix}/share/info --        sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/mpich2 --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-silent-rules --srcdir=. --enable-shared --prefix=/usr --enable-fc --disable-rpath --sysconfdir=/etc/mpich2 --includedir=/usr/include/mpich2 --docdir=/usr/share/doc/mpich2 --with-hwloc-prefix=system --enable-checkpointing
    MPICH2 CC:  gcc -g -O2 -g -Wall -O2   -O2
    MPICH2 CXX:     c++ -g -O2 -g -Wall -O2  -O2
    MPICH2 F77:     gfortran -g -O2  -O2
    MPICH2 FC:  f95   -O2
```